# Replace product name with custom meta in Woocommerce email downloads

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

Due to the plugin Essential Grid simply passing product titles to it's lightbox caption, to display sufficient product descriptions I am forced to have longer titles for products in my Woocommerce store. These longer titles are in turn being output in the WooCommerce order emails to the customer, including HTML tags - as seen below.

[Emails displaying long titles including HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAPoZ.png)

I have fixed this behaviour in my mini cart modal by calling for each product's custom meta of simple_title to be output rather than the default title, as seen below in my edited mini-cart.php (*** indicating my only changes)

```
<?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart_contents' );

        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            $_product     = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            $product_id   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            ***$meta_title = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'simple_title', true)***;
```

...

```
<?php echo str_replace( array( 'http:', 'https:' ), '', $thumbnail ) . ***$meta_title*** . '&nbsp;'; ?>
```

I would now like to implement the same solution in WooCommerce's email-downloads.php to fix my Woocommerce emails, but I cannot seem to get the 'get_post_meta' working in a 'foreach' in this file. Could anyone please share the correct formatting or where to insert this in the code below?

I have isolated the output part at least, to the

```
<?php echo esc_html( $download['product_name'] ); ?>
```

-- it is this output that needs to be replaced with displaying the simple_title custom meta of the product.

Many thanks in advance for any ideas.

```
<table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 40px;" border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ( $columns as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
            <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
</thead>

<?php foreach ( $downloads as $download ) : ?>

    <tr>
        <?php foreach ( $columns as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>;"><?php
                if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_email_downloads_column_' . $column_id ) ) {
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_email_downloads_column_' . $column_id, $download );
                } else {
                    switch ( $column_id ) {
                        case 'download-product' : ?>
                            <?php echo esc_html( $download['product_name'] ); ?>
                            <?php
                        break;
                        case 'download-file' : ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $download['download_url'] ); ?>" class="woocommerce-MyAccount-downloads-file button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $download['download_name'] ); ?></a>
                            <?php
                        break;
                        case 'download-expires' : ?>
                            <?php if ( ! empty( $download['access_expires'] ) ) : ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $download['access_expires'] ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( strtotime( $download['access_expires'] ) ); ?>"><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $download['access_expires'] ) ); ?></time>
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <?php _e( 'Never', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                            <?php endif;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 2 possible ways:

1) Using this filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_downloadable_items', 'custom_order_get_downloadable_items', 30, 2 );
function custom_order_get_downloadable_items( $downloads, $orders ){
    if( is_admin() )
        $downloads['product_name'] = get_post_meta( $downloads['product_id'], 'simple_title', true );

    return $downloads;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

---

2) [Override directly the template via your theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) and replace in `emails/email-downloads.php` file:

```
<?php echo esc_html( $download['product_name'] ); ?>
```

by:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( $downloads['product_id'], 'simple_title', true ); ?>
```

Comment: Really appreciate the input, but this hasn't had any effect on the emails unfortunately (still the long title). I do use a child theme and have tried adding this to my functions.php alongside my other filters there.

Comment: @daveisthemusic and if you remove `if( is_admin() )` what happen

Comment: It still doesn't work via functions.php unfortunately - however your solution helped me to fix it via email-downloads.php in the following way, so I'm very happy. Thanks.

`...else {
      switch ( $column_id ) {
       case 'download-product' : ?>
        <?php 
        $meta_title = get_post_meta( $download['product_id'], 'simple_title', true );
        echo esc_html( $meta_title ); ?>
        <?php
       break;
       case 'download-file' : ?>`

Comment: @daveisthemusic Yes of course you can override directly the email template as this is the same data in this email template… But I really don't catch why this filter is not working as it's in the function located in te function that output the data to this template… I can't test it now, for real, but I will do it later on to find out the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

I used solution from @loicTheAztec with a bit of modifications

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_downloadable_items', 'custom_order_get_downloadable_items', 30, 2 );
function custom_order_get_downloadable_items( $downloads, $orders ){

  $new_download = array();
  foreach($downloads as $dl){
    $new_name = sprintf( __('New Name %s' , 'my_project') , $dl['product_name'] );
    $dl['download_name'] = $new_name;

    $new_download[] =  $dl;
  }
  return $new_download;
}
```